# Low Download Speed by Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-explorer

I have an iso image(8 GB) in Azure Blob Storage. When I am trying to download through Azure Portal, it is taking too much time. When I am using Azure Storage Explorer to download, it takes very less time as compared to direct download from Azure Portal. Can anyone tell me the reason for the difference in download speed of Azure Storage Explorer and Azure Portal? Is there any way to speed up the download speed through Azure Portal?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this is off-topic, as it's not a programming question. There's really no way to know what's going on with your portal-based download. Plus, it's impossible to know what "taking too much time" means, as that's a very vague term.

Comment: Hi David, I will explain what I was trying to ask ,In Azure Storage Explore it is taking around 2 minutes, but through Azure Portal it is taking around 10-12 minutes with same network speed. Actually we need to provide a link through which a user can directly download the blob file. I wanted to know is there any way to speed up the download speed through azure portal?

Answer (score -1):

I tried with downloading some dummy large  file through the  [Azure storage explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/#overview) and [azure portal](https://portal.azure.com) :

Through portal it taking the little time

**Because Azure Storage Explorer is integrated with [azcopy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azcopy-support-in-azure-storage-explorer-now-available-in-public-preview/) which is using simple commands designed for optimal performance. So you can have a good-performance for downloading / uploading etc**

[image]

Same file with portal

[image]

You can also try with chucking the files ,By chunking the upload/download and make proper use of multi-threading.
For more details refer this SO Thread: [Best way to upload a blob with a huge size in GBs to azure in the fastest time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892957/best-way-to-upload-a-blob-with-a-huge-size-in-gbs-to-azure-in-the-fastest-time)

Comment: This doesn't really answer any question: the OP hasn't defined what "too much time" means. Plus this has nothing to do with programming. And the other SO question you're directing the OP to? That is related to *uploading*, and the selected Accepted Answer is a recommendation for a tool (that entire question and answer is off-topic now, and was closed as such 5 years ago)

Comment: One last thing, FYI - please don't ask people to accept your answer - there's no need.

Comment: Hi Shruti, Thanks for the response! So It means that azure storage explorer will always have higher speed than azure portal due to optimized AzCopy command it is using?

Comment: Hi Mohit Aggarwal, Ya as mentioned Azure storage explorer uses the AzCopy commands internally so speed is good for both upload and download,